# Creating a trusted MSI for installing Windows 10 programs

Tags: wix, windows-installer

I'm trying to put an application on my website so potential customers can down load it and run it.  I'm using WIX to create the MSI and I've got a GoDaddy code signing certificate.  The name of the MSI file is 'License Manager.msi', but when the screen blanks out during the install to ask permission, I get a dialog that states:

```
Do you want to allow this App to make changes to your device.

                   19e7696e.msi
```

The name of the MSI seems to change on every attempt to install.  Is this a Windows 10 thing or a WIX thing?  Where does this name come from and how can I replace it with the name of my application or something more informative?

Answer (score 3):

OK.  Found it.  It's part of SignTool.  The /d switch allows you to override the temporary MSI file created from the starting MSI file.